# Service fabric - Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : An error occurred during this operation

Tags: azure-service-fabric, octopus-deploy, service-fabric-on-premises

I have been tasked with updating Certificates on a service fabric cluster, I believe I have done this on the cluster but now octopus is producing this error. I have added the certificate into the machine and my users certificate stores and I can see the service fabric portal.

I can happily connect from the command line on the same machine, which I would imagine is what it is doing under the hood!

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "MyMachine.test.local:19000" -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint "ABCE35ECEDDEB4BB81039BC1745BA7087EBB8123" -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue "ABCE35ECEDDEB4BB81039BC1745BA7087EBB8123" -StoreLocation LocalMachine -StoreName My
```

Where might I find more detailed logs, where the heck are the so called **trace logs for more details**?

```
Loading connection parameters for the 'Client Certificate' security mode.
17:05:18   Verbose  |       Authenticating with Service Fabric.
17:05:18   Verbose  |       Using ConnectionParameters:
17:05:18   Verbose  |       ConnectionEndpoint=MyMachine.test.local:19000
17:05:18   Verbose  |       StoreLocation=LocalMachine
17:05:18   Verbose  |       FindType=FindByThumbprint
17:05:18   Verbose  |       ServerCertThumbprint=ABCE35ECEDDEB4BB81039BC1745BA7087EBB8123
17:05:18   Verbose  |       FindValue=ABCE35ECEDDEB4BB81039BC1745BA7087EBB8123
17:05:18   Verbose  |       X509Credential=True
17:05:18   Verbose  |       StoreName=MY
17:05:18   Error    |       Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : An error occurred during this operation.
17:05:18   Error    |       Please check the trace logs for more details.
17:05:18   Error    |       At C:\Octopus\Work\20221004160424-291654-3733\staging\Octopus.AzureServiceFabri
17:05:18   Error    |       cContext.ps1:210 char:16
17:05:18   Error    |       + ...      [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ClusterConnectionParameters ...
17:05:18   Error    |       +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
17:05:18   Error    |       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricClus
17:05:18   Error    |       ter], FabricException
17:05:18   Error    |       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.Service
17:05:18   Error    |       Fabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was that the octopus server where this is running also needed the certificate added to the machines **LocalMachine** **MY** (Personal) location. Once the certificate was added it deployed fine!

If we look at an example connection call we can see its asking for a certificate by the thumbprint, and this certificate needs to be on the machine that runs this command.

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "MyMachine.test.local:19000" -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint "ABCE35ECEDDEB4BB81039BC1745BA7087EBB8123" -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue "ABCE35ECEDDEB4BB81039BC1745BA7087EBB8123" -StoreLocation LocalMachine -StoreName My
```

Now to look at more shocking service fabric cluster issues :( ...